# In emacs, how to properly indent nested functions

Tags: php, emacs, indentation

In PHP code, I am currently using the following C indentation style:

```
(defconst my-c-style
  '((c-offsets-alist . ((arglist-close . 0)
                        (substatement-open . 0)
                        (case-label . +)))))
```

The problem is when I nest functions (or arrays). I want automatic indentation to format the following way:

```
myFunc(array(
    'arg1' => $val1,
    'arg2' => $val2,
    'arg3' => $val3,
    'arg4' => $val4,
));
```

But instead, what I get is:

```
myFunc(array(
           'arg1' => $val1,
           'arg2' => $val2,
           'arg3' => $val3,
           'arg4' => $val4,
       ));
```

The code inside always lines up with the 'a' from array. Is there a way to resolve this by modifying my C style? Currently I have to manually line up the closing parenthisis.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/5094649

Answer (score 0):

Try what is suggested [here](http://prajwalaa.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/using-emacs-to-edit-php-files/) if you are using the PHP-Mode.

Comment: The page linked does not address my question. If I use the configuration on that page my desired indentation does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Current php-mode releases as available via MELPA will out-of-the-box indent to your liking; I tried wordpress, pear, php and drupal indentation modes -- every one did what you want (drupal using 2 spaces per indentation step).

You can configure the indentation style either by setting `php-mode-coding-style` in your config, or try them out interactivly by calling `c-set-style` in a `php-mode` buffer, normaly bound to `C-c .`